# How to inject context using RoboGuice in Android?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I would like to inject my context to my Utility classes, I have seen [examples](http://www.rosscode.com/blog/index.php?title=android-development-part-3-wiring-up-roboguice&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) using Static fields, Are there any ways to do it with out static fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways, Pass the context to Utility class or use a service locator or anotate the utility class with `@Inject` attribute. See more details [here](http://www.irasenthil.com/2011/09/how-to-inject-context-in-android-with.html).

Comment: FYI, the linked article references the RoboGuice 1 way of doing things, not the newer RoboGuice 2+ way.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to use a [Provider](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/ProvidedInjections) to inject the context when I need it.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Provider<Context> contextProvider;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(Provider<Context> contextProvider)
    {
        this.contextProvider = contextProvider;
    }

    public doSomething()
    {
        Context c = contextProvider.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks pal, I was struggling with Context injection to land here.Thanks again  :)